# Execute window callback function in React component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm using a 3rd party Salesforce login script which executes an `onLogin` function callback on the `window` object with the authentication token and login name etc when the login succeeds.

To capture this event I have defined this function in my React component which should then do some queries and redux stuff however, React complains of an `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` when the `window.onLogin` callback fires. How do I execute my component code from a function executing outside the context of my React component?

```
const LoginPage = ({ actions }) => {

  const { validateIdentitySuccess } = actions;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const validateLogin = (identity) => {
      const { error, data } = doMyApolloQuery....
      if (data) {
        validateIdentitySuccess(identityStore);
      }
    };

    window.onLogin = (identity) => {
        validateLogin(identity); // ERROR GETS THROWN HERE 
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      .....
    </>
  );
};
```

The Salesforce documentation says to create a function called `onLogin` which will be called when the authentication succeeds:

```
<script>
   function onLogin(identity) {
      // ... identity contains login auth token etc
   }
<script>
```

Currently, I login, and then when `window.onLogin` fires I get the error.
Getting this tied into my React component is the issue.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and you didn't say what the error is